# Batch script to find and delete a value in multiple registry keys

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-registry

I have a batch script to [find an delete regedit key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141012/batch-script-to-find-and-delete-registry-keys-and-or-values):

```
@for %%I in ("foo") do reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%%~I" /f
```

I need to expand the search and removal of "foo" in other registry keys:

```
"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
```

How do I do it with a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I do it with a single command?

Use [brackets](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for %%I in ("foo") do (
  reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%%~I" /f
  reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%%~I" /f
  REM add more here
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions.
- [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: exceptional. thanks a lot